# Container of Generic Types in java

Tags: java

I have a generic class `Foo<T>` and parameterized types `Foo<String>` and `Foo<Integer>`. Now I want to put different parameterized types into a single `ArrayList`. What is the correct way of doing this?

Candidate 1:

```
public class MMM {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo<String> fooString = new Foo<String>();
        Foo<Integer> fooInteger = new Foo<Integer>();

        ArrayList<Foo<?> > list = new ArrayList<Foo<?> >();
        list.add(fooString);
        list.add(fooInteger);

        for (Foo<?> foo : list) {
            //  Do something on foo.
        }
    }
}
class Foo<T> {}
```

Candidate 2:

```
public class MMM {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo<String> fooString = new Foo<String>();
        Foo<Integer> fooInteger = new Foo<Integer>();

        ArrayList<Foo> list = new ArrayList<Foo>();
        list.add(fooString);
        list.add(fooInteger);

        for (Foo foo : list) {
            //  Do something on foo.
        }
    }
}
class Foo<T> {}
```

In a word, it is related to the difference between `Foo<?>` and the raw type `Foo`.

Update:

Grep *What is the difference between the unbounded wildcard parameterized type and the raw type?* on [this link](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#FAQ202) may be helpful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`List` represents a list with no type parameter. It is a list whose elements are of any type, e.g. the elements may be of different types. It's basically the same as `List<Object>`.

Meanwhile, `List<?>` represents a list with an unbounded type parameter. Its elements are of a specific, but unknown (before runtime), type. These elements all have to be from the same type at Runtime.

I recommend avoiding using raw types. The proper solution for your example is `List<Foo<?>>`.

Answer (score 4):

You want to avoid raw types whenever possible. The correct way to do it would be with 
`List<Foo<?>>`.